# AngularJS: count selected items on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with some custom controls.  At the bottom of this form, I need to display "numSelected of numRequired".  I know "numRequired", but how can I figure "numSelected"?

The form looks something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <fieldset ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="buttons" ng-init="selectedVal=1">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="item{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedVal" value="1" ng-selected="selectedVal==1">
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="item{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedVal" value="0" ng-selected="selectedVal==0">
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div>{{numSelected}} of {{numRequired}}</div>
</div>
```

I've tried tying `ng-click` and `ng-change` to each input and doing the counting in `MyCtrl` but I guess I don't know how to count items which meet conditions once I'm in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a count in scope

```
 $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.selectedIndex = {};
    $scope.count = function (index){
        $scope.selectedIndex[index] = 1;
        updateCount();
    }
    $scope.uncount = function (index){
        delete  $scope.selectedIndex[index];
        updateCount();
    }
    function updateCount(){
            var element_count =0;
             for (e in $scope.selectedIndex)
              { 
                element_count++; 
              }
         $scope.count = element_count;
    }
```

and ng-click as below

```
  <input type="radio" ng-click="count({{$index}})" name="item{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedVal" value="1" ng-selected="selectedVal==1">

 <input type="radio" ng-click="uncount({{$index}})" name="item{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedVal" value="1" ng-selected="selectedVal==1">
```

display count here

```
<div>{{count}} of {{numRequired}}</div>
```

Or **You can directly change count using ng-change**

```
<input type="radio" ng-change={{count + 1}} name="item{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedVal" value="1" ng-selected="selectedVal==1">

<input type="radio" ng-change={{count -1}} name="item{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedVal" value="1" ng-selected="selectedVal==1">
```

Comment: What if the user keeps clicking the same item over and over?  They'd still have one item selected, but the count would continue to climb.

Comment: I have edited the my answer to handle multiple clicks or you can try on-change instead of on-click with before answer

Comment: that'll do.  i used ng-change with a method that does the count +/-.