# bind ng-model to array size in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select that is populated with integers

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Lets say I have a collection of objects

```
  $scope.myCollection = [{"Color":"Red", "id":1},{"Color":"Blue", "id":2},
  {"Color":"Green","id":3}]
```

I would like to make a select that is bound to the number of items in the collection

This might looks something like this

```
<select ng-model="$scope.myCollection.Count">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

I realize that adding options like my example above is not really the way to go but it
gets my question across.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862764 see this question. Keep a count variable on the scope.

Comment: clearly I can keep a variable to do this but I was hoping to not have to store that value since its available as the number of items in the array

Comment: You could do it like this http://plnkr.co/edit/K26hfYj49qnEGSX25Vew?p=preview, but as long as you change the select, the `myCollection` array will be changed as well.

Comment: I must be missing something in your question but is there a reason you don't use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)?

Comment: I would normally use ng-options but for this example I just did it manually. My question is about using the length of the array to select an initial value by binding to the array lenght. After all the answers so far I think this might be a bad idea and I need to create a scope variable or an id on the elements in the array to accomplish what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
  <select ng-model="myCollection.length">
        <option ng-repeat="item in myCollection">{{$index+1}}</option>
    </select>
```

Live demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/c5ssmqyj/7/

**EDIT:**

This has a problem that when you will select any element, it will change the array length, that obviously you dont want.
So best way is to keep a count variable or a count function that returns the length

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP. You can make dynamic forms. One may look like this:

```
<select>
<?php
    while ($i=0, $i < $scope.myCollection.count, $i++){
        echo "<option>{$i}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: I will be surprise if this cannot be done in javascript. Regardless I am not working on a php platform. thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same, but using javascript instead.

```
function addOption(selectbox,text,value ){
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
}

for (var i=0; i < someArray.length;++i){
    addOption(document.selectbox, someText, value);
}
```

I found a pretty good explanation of dynamic javascript forms [here.](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/list-adding.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-repeat` to bind the `option` to the collection

```
  <select>
   <option ng-repeat="item in myCollection">{{item.id}}</option>
  </select>
```

where the collection items have an `id` field with the number or anything else you would like displayed in your dropdown